# how to display the unique number in 2d array and sum the unique number

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.io.*;
public class Arrayact {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader cin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int row, maxRow, col, maxCol;
        int yctr = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int y;
        System.out.print("Number of row/s: ");
        maxRow = Integer.parseInt(cin.readLine());
        System.out.print("Number of colmun/s: ");
        maxCol = Integer.parseInt(cin.readLine());
        int arr[][] = new int[maxRow][maxCol];
        System.out.println();

        for (row = 0; row < maxRow; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < maxCol; col++) {
                System.out.print("Index[" + row + "][" + col + "]: ");
                arr[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(cin.readLine());
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
        for (row = 0; row < maxRow; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < maxCol; col++) {
                y = arr[row][col];
                if (arr[row][col] == y) {
                    yctr++;
                    sum += arr[row][col];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("ther are " + yctr + "unique element and their sum is " + sum);
    }
}
```

here is my code, i want to display the unique number and the sum of the unique number, but im just getting the number of input and the whole sum of the input. anyone knows what the wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  in order to get good answers please show what you have tried and what is the logic behind it. in the code you put here can you please explain the logic behind it ?

Comment: You could use a `Set`.

Comment: Theres is a column and row and then you will input numbers then. After you input the numbers the program is gonna display how many unique numbers are there. And then the unique numbers will add and show the equals.

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor the part that calculates the sum of unique elements to use a `Set`, a data structure that can hold unique elements. So, for each `y` you can check if it exists in the set, and if it doesn't you add it to the sum and add this number to the set so that it doesn't get added to the sum again.

```
        Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>();

        for (row = 0; row < maxRow; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < maxCol; col++) {
                y = arr[row][col];
                if (!numbers.contains(y)) {
                    numbers.add(y);
                    sum += y;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("ther are " + numbers.size() + "unique element and their sum is " + sum);
```

Comment: san you please elaborate ? the set and hashset is cannot find sysmbol. what should i do

Comment: Here's i want to do, Number of row/s: 5
Number of colmun/s: 3

Index[0][0]: 1
Index[0][1]: 2
Index[0][2]: 5
Index[1][0]: 6
Index[1][1]: 4
Index[1][2]: 85
Index[2][0]: 85
Index[2][1]: 4
Index[2][2]: 1
Index[3][0]: 2
Index[3][1]: 6
Index[3][2]: 1
Index[4][0]: 8
Index[4][1]: 1
Index[4][2]: 3

ther are 3 unique element and their sum is 17. so basically in row and columns it will compare all of the input number then tell if there is duplicate number then it will display only the unique number that has no duplicate

Comment: I tried to use your code. And it work but on in 1 column and row. Can show me how to to compare them all?